# WinSCP SFTP script – Skip unavailable host instead of waiting

Tags: windows, batch, sftp, winscp

I have a script which is copying from a remote server to my local PC. Batch File is running but when the IP 10.223.19.51 is down/powered off script will not run the next commandline. It gives me an error. See script below. Please help.. I want that even the other servers are down script will continue or it will run to the next commandline..

```
C:\db_backup> cd\
C:> cd Program Files (x86)/
C:\Program Files (x86)> cd WinSCP/
C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP> winscp.com /script=POS.txt
Searching for host...
Network error: Connection to "10.223.19.51" timed out.
C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP> pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

This is the script::

```
open sftp://pos:pos@10.223.19.51/
recv -neweronly /opt/simplepos/data/rsalphaland/*.zip C:\db_backup\POS\Lane1\
open sftp://pos:pos@10.223.19.52/
recv -neweronly /opt/simplepos/data/rsalphaland/*.zip C:\db_backup\POS\Lane2\
open sftp://pos:pos@10.223.19.53/
recv -neweronly /opt/simplepos/data/rsalphaland/*.zip C:\db_backup\POS\Lane3\
open sftp://pos:pos@10.223.19.54/
recv -neweronly /opt/simplepos/data/rsalphaland/*.zip C:\db_backup\POS\Lane4\
open sftp://pos:pos@10.223.19.55/
recv -neweronly /opt/simplepos/data/rsalphaland/*.zip C:\db_backup\POS\Lane5\
open sftp://pos:pos@10.223.19.56/
recv -neweronly /opt/simplepos/data/rsalphaland/*.zip C:\db_backup\POS\Lane6\
open sftp://pos:pos@10.223.19.57/
recv -neweronly /opt/simplepos/data/rsalphaland/*.zip C:\db_backup\POS\Lane7\
open sftp://pos:pos@10.223.19.58/
recv -neweronly /opt/simplepos/data/rsalphaland/*.zip C:\db_backup\POS\Lane8\
exit
```

Comment: Your question title does not match your text. In title you say *"Skip instead of waiting"*. While in text you say *"continue on error"*. - Also I do not understand the difference between *"will continue"* and *"will run to the next commandline"*. - Anyway, I'll try to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [`option batch` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_option#batch):

```
option batch continue
```